# Primefaces Schedule Component eventMove issue

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using primeface schedule component and having an issue onEventMove event. My event handler method is as the following:

```
    public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {

        /* I put the id of my object as data of schedule event 
         * while I constructed  event model.
         */

        String id = (String) event.getScheduleEvent().getData();

        /* And when the move event occure, find my object by 
         * using the data of the moved event.
         */

        MyObject myObject = myObjectManager.findMyObject(id);

        /* MyObject also have two attributes, startDate and endDate
         */

        Date startTime = myObject.getStartDate();
        Date endTime = myObject.getEndDate();

        /* I print out startDate and endDate of MyObject and
         * new start date and end date of moved event
         */        

        System.out.println(startTime);
        System.out.println(endTime);
        System.out.println(event.getScheduleEvent().getStartDate());
        System.out.println(event.getScheduleEvent().getEndDate());
    }
```

My issue here is that the output are being same. I mean the output of the statement:

```
System.out.println(startTime);
```

is same with the output of

```
System.out.println(event.getScheduleEvent().getStartDate());
```

and also the output of the statement

```
System.out.println(endTime);
```

is being same with

```
System.out.println(event.getScheduleEvent().getEndDate());
```

Can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong please?

**myObjectManager** is an instance of EJB stateless session bean and the souce code of **myObjectManager.findMyObject(id)** is as following:

```
public MyObject findMyObject(String id) {
    return myObjectEAO.find(id);
}
```

**myObjectEAO** is also an instance of EJB stateless session bean and the source code of **myObjectEAO.find(id)** is as following:

```
public MyObject find(String id) {
    // em, here, is an instance of entity manager
    return em.find(MyObject.class, id);
}
```

Comment: what does myObjectManager.findMyObject do. Post some source.

Comment: hello roel, myObjectManager is an instance of EJB stateless session bean. i appended the source of myObjectManager.findMyObject.

Comment: is made my own test case and apparently the object is directly updated with the new dates/times when moving an event.

Comment: thanks roel. yes you are right. it appears like this and it does not make sense i think. the value of myObject.getStartDate() is from database and the value of event.getScheduleEvent().getStartDate() is from schedule's move event. they should not be same.

Comment: post your MyObject.class source, <p:schedule source and your bean source attached to <p:schedule value="yourbean....

Comment: I have the same problem @roel did you understand any thing from this problem, i get the same problem, the Object set always the Start and End date of the event in his attributes? i really don't know where is the problem, thank you to provide some explanation if you understand